# No se abre el navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigationview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android Studio, en la que utilizo un NavigationDrawer. El problema lo tengo cuando al pinchar en el botón que abriría el menú del navigation no lo hace pero si me permite arrastrar el navigation de izquierda a derecha para que se vea. ¿Como se podría solucionar y por qué no llama al listener?. La actividad tiene dos fragmentos. El layout es el siguiente:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" >


    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/listar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/detalles"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/cabecera"
    app:menu="@layout/menu_drawer" />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

El código relevante de la actividad es el siguiente:

```
public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    Toolbar appbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    setSupportActionBar(appbar);
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (findViewById(R.id.detalles) != null) {
        mTwoPanes = true;

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Details fragment = Details.newInstance(null, null);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.detalles, fragment).commit();
        }
    }


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {

            prepararDrawer(navigationView);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {

                List fragmentoGenerico = new List();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.lista, fragmentoGenerico).commit();
            }else {
                seleccionarItem(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(0));
            }
            }

}
private void prepararDrawer(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    seleccionarItem(menuItem);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });

}
```

El siguiente método no llega a llamarse, por lo que no abre el drawer:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        break;

        default:

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    return true;

}
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarse?

Comment: En donde no se abre, desde un elemento del menú ?

Comment: Si, tengo el típico elemento de la izquierda que cuando se selecciona abre el navigation drawer. Así no lo hace, sin embargo si lo arrastro si.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes definido en tu Layout el `DrawerLayout`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/cabecera"
    app:menu="@layout/menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Esto para poder tener la referencia en tu código:

```
 drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

El problema que se encontró es que no se tenía implentado el método

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
```

por esta razón no se ejecutaba el método que abría el `DrawerLayout`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

Comment: Al copiar el código del layout me faltó una parte. Ya lo edité

Comment: @adamista ok entonces revisa mi respuesta debes usar case R.id.home: , agrega por favor el layout de tu menú

Comment: El menú se lo agrego dinámicamente a la toolbar desde la actividad. No tengo un layout. Se lo agrego con Toolbar appbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    setSupportActionBar(appbar);
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: He probado lo que me indicas y no funciona. No llama al método

Comment: pero si llega a esa linea de código?

Comment: no, no llega ni al método onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: Tienes el método @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  en tu activity?

Comment: Lo tenía comentado, pensé que no hacía falta. Ahora ya funciona. Muchas gracias :D